# How can I pass JSON response from http request to jsr223 assertion using groovy in Jmeter?

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I have an API which returns following result:

```
{"success":true,
  "error":null,
  "data": {"EmpId":444,"ProfileNo":0,"ProfileName":"xya","Rank":0,"ScoreValue":0,"CompanyEmpID":"A25842"}}
```

I need to pass above JSON to JSR223 assertion to verify all the output values individually. I managed to write the following script

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
JsonSlurper JSON = new JsonSlurper ();

def expected = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('Employee 
data'))
def actual = new 
groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData({"success":true,
"error":null,
"data":

{"EmpId":444,
 "ProfileNo":0,
 "ProfileName":"xya","Rank":0,"ScoreValue":0,"CompanyEmpID":"A25842"}})

 if (expected != actual) {
 AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
 AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Mismatch between expected and actual 
 JSON')
  }
```

But its failing.Iam getting the error as follow:

Assertion error: true
Assertion failure: false
Assertion failure message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script20.groovy: 10: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 10, column 81.
   rev.getResponseData({"success":true,
                                 ^

1 error

Answer (score 0):

The correct code would be something like:

```
def expected = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText('{"success":true,\n' +
        '  "error":null,\n' +
        '  "data": {"EmpId":444,"ProfileNo":0,"ProfileName":"xya","Rank":0,"ScoreValue":0,"CompanyEmpID":"A25842"}}')

def actual = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

if (expected != actual) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Mismatch between expected and actual JSON ')
}
```

However it would work only for first level values, if you will be using the approach to compare nested JSON objects - you will get false positive results, so it would be better to go for i.e. [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-compare-two-json-objects) or [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) libraries which perform "deep scan", check out [The Easiest Way To Compare REST API Responses Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-easiest-way-to-compare-rest-api-responses-using-jmeter/) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks alot @dmitri-t it worked for me!!
I was wondering if I want to write the expected results in an excel file and could compare it with same Json (output of my API call), how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use json assertion to validate the value as shown below;-

Json Request with response (dummy Samlper used)
[image]

Put assertion path and expected value.
[image]
Below i have change value to see if it works and fail if the value change. Else it work as expected.
[image]

Hope this helps.
This is not related to JSR223 but using json assertion.